# Latest version of Google Prediction API on Google Apps Script please

Tags: google-apps-script, google-prediction

I have successfully added Google Prediction API on my Google Apps Script. However the version selector shows only 1.2 for the Prediction API. The latest version is 1.5 and it has been released for a few months now. Can we have the latest version of the Google APIs on apps script please? Or did I just miss something?

Answer (score 1):

Version 1.5 of the Prediction API is now supported in Apps Script.